# GNU parser Optimization Using L-System

Tags: c, l-systems

Any suggestion on how to use **Lindenmeyer** System approach (L-System) to make the GNU parser faster through parallelism. I also need to compare the normal execution time and execution time when the L-system is implemented for the **C** language. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad for this format.  Note that you can write a very efficient parser for the C language without the L-System, the TinyCC compiler is a good example of a hand written C parser written int the C language that is **very** efficient. Check it out at http://tinycc.org

Comment: optimizing it is my project for my degree.. I need to use l-system..any suggetion plz